# sf create polygon from minimum x and y coordinates

Tags: r, sf

I am trying to create a `polygon` from a `coordinate` `dataframe`. I have the minimum and maximum x-y coordinate information. But, I am getting the following error. How can this be fixed?

```
library(tidyverse)
library(sf)
lon = c(756065.70, 757428.78)
lat = c(4074435.19,4075144.12)

Poly_Coord_df = data.frame(lon, lat)

Poly = Poly_Coord_df %>% 
  st_as_sf(coords = c("lon", "lat"), crs = 32611) %>% 
  summarise((geometry = st_combine(geometry))) %>% 
  st_cast("POLYGON")
```

Error

```
Error in h(simpleError(msg, call)) : 
  error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 'plot': polygons require at least 4 points
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've only got two points so you need to construct five to complete a box.

I don't understand what all that pipeline is supposed to do, the simplest and most direct way is to use `st_polygon` and feed it a list of a matrix which has five rows and two columns by taking the elements from your data frame:

```
> pol = st_polygon(
     list(
       cbind(
         Poly_Coord_df$lon[c(1,2,2,1,1)], 
         Poly_Coord_df$lat[c(1,1,2,2,1)])
       )
    )
```

which returns:

```
POLYGON ((756065.7 4074435, 757428.8 4074435, 757428.8 4075144, 756065.7 4075144, 756065.7 4074435))
```

You probably then want to add the coordinate system and convert to an `sfc`:

```
polc = st_sfc(pol, crs=32611)


> polc
Geometry set for 1 feature 
Geometry type: POLYGON
Dimension:     XY
Bounding box:  xmin: 756065.7 ymin: 4074435 xmax: 757428.8 ymax: 4075144
Projected CRS: WGS 84 / UTM zone 11N
POLYGON ((756065.7 4074435, 757428.8 4074435, 7...
```

How it works - the `sf_polygon` function needs a *matrix* with two columns, with points in rows, the first point and the last point being the same to complete the polygon. For example to construct a "unit square" polygon between (0,0) and (1,1) you could make the matrix by making the columns and combining with `cbind`:

```
> cbind(c(0,1,1,0,0), c(0,0,1,1,0))
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    0    0
[2,]    1    0
[3,]    1    1
[4,]    0    1
[5,]    0    0
```

And you can feed that into `st_polygon`, wrapping it in a `list` because polygons can be complex features with more than one "ring".

```
> st_polygon(list(cbind(c(0,1,1,0,0), c(0,0,1,1,0))))
POLYGON ((0 0, 1 0, 1 1, 0 1, 0 0))
```

Plotting that shows a square:

[image]

For your specific data frame, you get the latitudes as a vector like this:

```
> Poly_Coord_df$lat
[1] 4074435 4075144
```

and if you get them in the right order by subsetting:

```
> Poly_Coord_df$lat[c(1,1,2,2,1)]
[1] 4074435 4074435 4075144 4075144 4074435
```

that gets you the latitudes for making a polygon. A similar subset gets them in the right order for the longitude, and then binding them together you can feed them to `sf_polygon`.

Comment: Can you please briefly explain what does `Poly_Coord_df$lon[c(1,2,2,1,1)]` mean?

Comment: "briefly" it is standard R data frame column extraction and subsetting, which is normally taught in first steps in R. Not sure how you missed that.

Comment: "Please consider adding a comment if you think this post can be improved." Removing your condescending comment replying to the OP would improve this post.

`Poly_Coord_df$lon[c(1,2,2,1,1)]` takes the two-element vector of longitudes (the `Poly_Coord_df$lon` part), and creates a new, 5-element vector of longitudes by extracting the 1st, 2nd, 2nd, 1st, and 1st elements of the two-element vector using square bracket notation (the `[c(1,2,2,1,1)]` part).

Answer (score 11):

In the specific context you describe - having top right and bottom left corner of your desired polygon - you may be able to get by with `sf::st_bbox()`. It returns the bounding box of an object, in your case of the `Poly_Coords_df` data frame (as intepreted in context of EPSG:32611).

```
poly <- Poly_Coord_df %>% 
  st_as_sf(coords = c("lon", "lat"), 
           crs = 32611) %>% 
  st_bbox() %>% 
  st_as_sfc()
```